# Does a USB 4G dongle connected to a router perform differently to a router with a 4G SIM slot built-in

Tags: router, cpu, routing, mobile-broadband

I think I covered the question in that beasty title but I'll give some background to the question.

We are organising a charity LAN event and need a method of getting reliable Internet access via 4G for say 15+ computers. We've narrowed it down to a 4G USB dongle connected to a router and connection sharing, versus a router with a 4G SIM slot built-in.

My question is are these two solutions any different?

I personally suspect that the USB dongle might process the packets it receives which incurs an extra overhead and so whilst you get the same top-end bandwidth, you might actually only be able to process fewer packets per second compared to a router with a 4G SIM.

Another solution was a MiFi device, but these often state 5-10 devices maximum which leads me to conclude that they are processing packets and cannot handle the extra overhead from more devices. A 4G router with SIM slot for example states 32 devices maximum.

Edit: The event will be approximately 15 desktop PCs playing games on Internet-based servers, so relatively low bandwidth but very high throughput.

I pulled apart an old 3G dongle earlier and found a Qualcomm chip, the MDM8200a. This appears to handle everything from USB through to pushing out to the physical layer RF chip. I'm beginning to think that wouldn't be a bottleneck...

Answer (score 0):

Even though the router allows 32 devices, I very much doubt the USB dongle itself could handle those connections to the internet simultaneously. Not sure if the device would block connections once it reached a threshold. Most 4G USB dongles would handle less than a MiFi device and the specs are usually max 5 devices if sharing via a laptop/desktop.

In any case, I agree that the router can handle networking better. It all comes down to the use case and what actions you'll be performing on the network (eg simple web browsing). Would be worth mentioning this in your question.

---

On a side note, be sure to research compatibility of devices if using the USB/Router solution.

Comment: Why do you think a USB dongle wouldn't be able to handle lots of connections, they support the full 4G bandwidth so what's the bottleneck? I'll add something about use case to the question.

Comment: I didn't say anything about 4G not having the bandwidth. I'm talking purely about the USB device itself. It's the concurrent connections to the mobile network that is the issue.

Comment: Why though, what do you think will cause more concurrent connections to the mobile network to be a problem? Will that be the same whether I use a USB dongle or native SIM slot?